# Message: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

I encounter the following error on an application with the following PHP version:
Could you please help me an say if I could change something on PHP version it would work. I tried to find something with this error but was on their specific code. I have to mention that I m more an application administrator with Linux skills than PHP developer.

```
PHP 7.4.9 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2020 08:28:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

> A PHP Error was encountered
> Severity: Warning
> Message: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
> Filename: libraries/MY_HTML.php
> Line Number: 89

CODE:

```
 /**
     * 
     * @param string $name - select element "name" atribute
     * @param (array or stdClass) $option_array - option array with value and text
     * @param int $selectedIndex - which index is selected bby default
     * @param string $spec - selectbox specifications (html code, example: "id=\"select\" style=\"background-color: #FFF;\"")
     * @param string $selectedValue - option with this "value" is selected
     * @return string - select element to be printed
     */


        function createHolidaySelectBox($name, $option_array,
      $selectedIndex = 0, $spec = "", $selectedValue = NULL) {
            $select_box = "<select name=\"$name\" " . $spec . ">";
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($option_array as $v) {
                if ($v->isActive()) {
                    if (sizeof($v) < 2) {
                        $val = array_keys($option_array, $v);
                        $opt = array($val[0], $v);
                    } else {
                        $opt = $v;
                    }
    
                    $select_box.="<option value=\"" . $opt[0] . "\"" .               (($selectedValue == NULL) ? ($i == $selectedIndex ? " selected" : "") : 
 (($opt[0] == $selectedValue) ? " selected" : "")) . ">" . $opt[1] .                                 "</option>";
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            $select_box.="</select>";
            return $select_box;
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: `$v` is a value, not an array.

Comment: and if I would downgrade the php version would treat $v as a value to dont display this warning?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

This piece

```
if ($v->isActive()) {
    if (sizeof($v) < 2) {
        $val = array_keys($option_array, $v);
        $opt = array($val[0], $v);
    } else {
        $opt = $v;
    }
```

should be changed in this way

```
if ($v->isActive()) {
    if (is_array($v) && sizeof($v) < 2) {
        $val = array_keys($option_array, $v);
        $opt = array($val[0], $v);
    } else {
        $opt = $v;
    }
```

this is because looking at your code you are expecting either a value (like string, bool int etc.) or an array